# Excluding Webpack externals with library components / fragments

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

Webpack has been very useful to us in writing isomorphic Javascript, and swapping out `npm` packages for browser globals when bundling.

So, if I want to use the `node-fetch` `npm` package on Node.js but exclude it when bundling and just use the native browser `fetch` global, I can just mention it in my `webpack.config.js`:

```
{
  externals: {
    'node-fetch': 'fetch',
    'urlutils': 'URL',
    'webcrypto': 'crypto', // etc
  }
}
```

And then my CommonJS requires `const fetch = require('node-fetch')` will be transpiled to `const fetch = window.fetch` (or whatever it does).

So far so good. **Here's my question:** This is easy enough when requiring entire modules, but what about when I need to require a submodule / individual property of an exported module?

For example, say I want to use the WhatWG [URL standard](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/), isomorphically. I could use the `urlutils` `npm` module, which `module.exports` the whole URL class, so my requires look like:

```
const URL = require('urlutils')
```

And then I can list `urlutils` in my `externals` section, no prob. But the moment I want to use a more recent (and more supported) `npm` package, say, `whatwg-url`, I don't know how to Webpack it, since my requires look like:

```
const { URL } = require('whatwg-url')
// or, if you don't like destructuring assignment
const URL = require('whatwg-url').URL
```

How do I tell Webpack to replace occurrences of `require('whatwg-url').URL` with the browser global `URL`?

Comment: Refactoring not an option?

Comment: But what would one refactor it *to*?

Comment: I think you might be asking for practically impossible thing. Let's assume the `URL` is a function and it lives in a massive file. Webpack would have to go to that file and trace all the code which is needed for the `URL` function. Webpack is file bundler, it can't split and merge dependencies based on requested properties.

Comment: Hmm, I think I didn't explain the question clearly enough, my apologies. It's not that I want Webpack to only *pack* the URL function. It can stuff in the whole npm package, no problem. What I need is for the require()s to work transparently, between Node and the browser.

Comment: @DmitriZagidulin ok, but you understand that it would pack both modules for Web, I'm not sure if you want that, since on the web you want to save each KB. If you don't care about size, I think I have an idea how you could achieve what you want.

Comment: re both modules - no, I only brought up 'urlutils' as an example (of webpack making a require operation a straightforward map to a global). I just want to use 'whatwg-url', preferably without a re-export.

Answer (score 1):

At first I would like to highlight that I am not a webpack expert. I think there is a better way of bundling during the build time. Anyway, here is my idea:

`webpack.config.js`

```
  module.exports = {
    target: "web",
    entry: "./entry.js",
    output: {
      path: __dirname,
      filename: "bundle.js"
    }
  };
```

`entry.js`

```
  var URL = require("./content.js");
  document.write('Check console');
  console.log('URL function from content.js', URL);
```

`content.js`

```
  let config = require('./webpack.config.js');
  let urlutils = require('urlutils');
  let whatwgUrl = require('whatwg-url');

  console.log('urlutils:', urlutils);
  console.log('whatwgUrl', whatwgUrl);

  module.exports = {
    URL: undefined
  };

  if (config.target === 'web') {
    module.exports.URL = urlutils;
  } else {
    module.exports.URL = whatwgUrl.URL;
  }
```

`index.html`

```
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

As I said in the comment, it's going to bundle two libs for the Web bundle - waste of space.

Now, for NodeJS, you change the `target` from `web` to `node` and it should take the other library. https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#target

I've found a module for 'isomorphic' apps: https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/universal-webpack

I think you could try to use two, separate middle `content.js` files as a parameters for the module. One containing `urlutis` and the second `whatwg-url`. Then it would dynamically recognize what it compiles your files for and use the proper module.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This isn't quite it, in that I'm looking for a way to map require('whatwg-url').URL to a browser global without a re-export via content.js. I do appreciate the effort you've put in, though, so I'm going to select this answer for the bounty.

Comment: @DmitriZagidulin So are you looking for a way to automatically export and map these packages? I can imagine if you have quite a lot such dependencies you would have to craft an automatic solution by yourself. Check the link for universal-webpack, I'm pretty sure, that it's possible to create such mapping with this module, during built process and without exposing webpack config to the web. Thanks for the bounty.